# Error when upgrading Azure function EventHub trigger to programming model v4. Does this have to do with missing setting "dataType": "binary"?

Tags: typescript, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to migrate my Azure function from the v3 to the v4 programming model. If I try to trigger the refactored function I'm getting the following error:

```
[2023-10-24T08:05:30.375Z] Executed 'Functions.location-updates' (Failed, Id=caeb8080-79aa-4230-b7f7-541111ef99bb, Duration=65ms)
[2023-10-24T08:05:30.375Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.location-updates. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'eventHubTrigger1'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Binding parameters to complex objects (such as 'Object') uses Json.NET serialization. 
[2023-10-24T08:05:30.375Z] 1. Bind the parameter type as 'string' instead of 'Object' to get the raw values and avoid JSON deserialization, or
[2023-10-24T08:05:30.376Z] 2. Change the queue payload to be valid json. The JSON parser failed: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Path '', line 0, position 0.
```

With programmig model v3 I specified `"dataType": "binary"` in the `function.json` file, but with v4 this is not possible in the options of `app.eventHub(name, options)`. I think this might be causing the error.

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger configuration like methods and AuthLevel, datatype that were specified in a function.json file before are moved to the code itself in V4.

There have been some changes, and "dataType: binary" is not used anymore.

- The Event Hub trigger expects messages to be deserialized as JSON by default. If your Event Hub messages are not in JSON format, you will need to handle the deserialization yourself.
- To do this, you should bind the parameter as a string and then manually deserialize the message inside your function code.

```
module.exports = async function (context, eventHubMessages) {
    for (const message of eventHubMessages) {
    
        // For example, if the message is a binary format, you can decode it to a string
        const decodedMessage = Buffer.from(message, 'base64').toString('utf8');
        
        // Now you can work with the decoded message as a string
        context.log(decodedMessage);
    }
};
```

In v4, bind the parameter as a string and manually handle the deserialization of messages if they are not in JSON format. For more details take this [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/azure-functions-version-4-of-the-node-js-programming-model-is-in/ba-p/3773541) as a reference.

Comment: Cool, this is helpful. The part that I still don't understand is how to "bind the paramter as a string". How do I do that in TypeScript?